# KeyError: 'Date' - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i've this dataframe

```
Open    High    Low Close   Volume  Currency
Date                        
2019-12-10  2.6567  2.6640  2.5761  2.6034  169699712   USD
2019-12-11  2.6033  2.6207  2.5489  2.5767  142513840   USD
2019-12-12  2.5767  2.6144  2.5127  2.5827  205298528   USD
2019-12-13  2.5827  2.6410  2.5737  2.6248  154753008   USD
2019-12-14  2.6248  2.6295  2.5495  2.5652  151872096   USD
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2020-03-13  1.7755  2.2559  1.3956  2.1111  1237484160  USD
2020-03-14  2.1087  2.1265  1.9336  1.9617  490464256   USD
2020-03-15  1.9617  2.1347  1.9406  2.0464  362441408   USD
2020-03-16  2.0465  2.0533  1.7260  1.8913  472691392   USD
2020-03-17  1.8913  2.0247  1.8737  1.9731  317900000   USD
```

but when i try to do `df_dates = df.loc[:,'Date']` it get me an

```
KeyError: 'Date'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
```

what is wrong in my code?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVR
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
import investpy

today = datetime.today().strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

df = investpy.get_crypto_historical_data(crypto='EOS', from_date='10/12/2019', to_date=today)
print(df.head())

dates = []

df_dates = df.loc[:,'Date']
df_open = df.loc[:,'Close'] 
prices = []
```

Comment: Date is `index`, so need `df_dates = df.index`